# strings and split then insert into html table

Tags: php, string

i want to split this string by the (*) sign

```
$string="
How Many Papers*On My Table
How Many Mobiles*Your Brother have
";
```

i want to split them and insert them in a html table like this

```
<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>How Many Papers</td>
        <td>On My Table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>How Many Mobiles</td>
        <td>Your Brother have</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here: splitting into lines to be used as `<tr>`s, and splitting each row to be used as `<td>`s:

To get each line, you want to first trim your original string to get rid of leading and trailing newlines (so you don't end up with empty lines in your array), then you can use `explode()` to create an array of lines delimited by the newline character:

```
$trimmedString = trim($string);
$lines = explode("\n", $trimmedString);
```

You can also compress these two into a single line to eliminate the need for the temporary `$trimmedString` variable:

```
$lines = explode("\n", trim($string));
```

Next, you want to use a `foreach` loop to iterate over each line. You'll create your table rows here, and use `explode()` again to break up the line based on the asterisks. You'll use another `foreach` loop to create the table data elements themselves:

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo "<tr>";

  $elements = explode("*", $line);
  foreach($elements as $element) {
    echo "<td>" . $element . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

```
$string="
How Many Papers*On My Table
How Many Mobiles*Your Brother have
";

// To split by newline
$tmp = explode("\n", $string); 
// To split by *
$data = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
    $data[] = explode("*", $tmp[$i]);
}
```

Comment: how to insert them into html table as i asked bro

Comment: You asked how to split them, not how to insert them into a html table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = explode("\n", (explode('*', $string)));

echo '<table border="1" width="100%" id="table1">';
foreach ($array as $row) {
  echo 'tr>'
  foreach ($row as $sr) {
    echo '<td>'.$sr.'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ( foreach ($row as $sr) { )

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this.  In your first line, the asterisk-explode will return an array, but your newline-explode expects that argument to be a string, so it'll fail right there. Even if it had worked, you would have eliminated the only way to distinguish between rows. You would end up with a single-row table where the end elements are self-contained, but the middle elements would contain multiple rows. No offense, but you should really test your code before presenting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a twodimensional array...

so spontaneously i would take something like that:

```
$line = array();
$line = explode( "\n" , $string );

$cell = array();

for ( $i = 0; != sizeof($line); $i++ ) {
    $cell[$i] = array();
    $cell[$i] = explode("*", $line[$i]);
}
```

So you have got a two dimensional array like this: $cell[linenumber][cellnumber]

To print the cells in a table i would prefer nested foreach loops:

```
foreach ( $cell as $row_number -> $row_array ) {
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach ( $row_array as $cell_number -> $cell_content ) {
       echo "<td>" . $cell_content . "</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Please have a look and if something is wrong or I have made some mistakes please correct me ;)